# Restarting WPF App changes Mainwindow thread owner

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a pretty intense threading application that works great... however when a restart button is clicked... it follows through the code, disposes the viewmodels and closes the mainwindow... thus returning the dialogresult and returning back to app.xaml.cs.

This is how I've implemented restart...

```
base.OnStartup(e);

        // Register required assemblies.
        RegisterAssemblies();

        foreach (FolderType type in FolderType.GetValues())
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(type.Value))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(type.Value);
            }
        }

        bool? restart = true;
        ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
        dynamic window;
        MainWindowViewModel viewModel;

        while (restart == true)
        {
            running = true;
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FolderType.LASTCONFIGURATION.Value);
            lastConfiguration = string.Empty;

            if (files.Length != 0)
            {
                lastConfiguration = files[0];
            }

#if (!DEBUG)
            if (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight == 1080)
            {
                window = new MainWindowHD();
            }
            else
            {
                window = new MainWindow();
            }

            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
#else
            window = new MainWindow();
#endif

            window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(lastConfiguration, "saved_settings.xml", FolderType.CASES + "\\" + "case_configuration.xml");

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    window.DataContext = viewModel;
                }
            ));

            restart = window.ShowDialog();
        }

        if (systemShutdown)
        {
            Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
        }

        Shutdown(0);
```

This in turns loops again and resets the window object and the viewmodel object but now Application.Current.MainWindow in all my other classes complain about a different thread owning it. I think I get by this by putting ((App)Application).Dispatcher.Invoke however I'd prefer not to as there was no need before the restart.

What could explain Application.Current.MainWindow not being of the same thread it was created on?

Cheers.

Comment: Just checked Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke and Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke but the MainWindow seems to be on a completed different thread!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MainWindow` property is only set when the first `Window` is created in the application. When you recreate the window, you'll need to update the `MainWindow` property manually.

Also, you don't need to use `Application.Current` if your code is running in an override of the `OnStartup` method of the `Application`.

```
this.MainWindow = window = new MainWindow();
window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(...);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => window.DataContext = viewModel));
restart = window.ShowDialog();
```

---

One other comment: don't forget that HD screens might have a resolution greater than 1080p. You should update your check to account for this:

```
if (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight >= 1080)
```

Comment: this.MainWindow = window = new MainWindow() isn't fixing this... I had actually tried setting it by Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow this morning but didn't work either. When debugging just before the error... I can look into some of the MainWindow properties but others such as Style says it needs to continue execution to re-evaluate.